# Why visual studio code xdebug using php version 8.1.4 even though my current php version enabled in wamp is 7.4

Tags: php, wamp, vscode-extensions, xdebug

please help!
My when i debug my php code in visual studio code using xdebug it always start the server with php8.4.1 , eventhough my selected php version of wamp server is 7.4.please help me to use php 7.4 for xdebug

changed php 8.1.4 to php 7.4 but no luck

Comment: PHP 7.x are all end of life, so don't expect tools to keep supporting them.

Comment: but in another pc with only php7.4 debug is working

Comment: Is 7.4's folder in the PATH in the environment variables?  If only 8.x's folder is there, and possibly if 8.4's folder comes earlier in the path, VSCode is probably finding it first.